# How to rename an existing Spark SQL function

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am using Spark to call functions on the data which is submitted by the user.

How can I rename an already existing function to a different name like like `REGEXP_REPLACE` to `REPLACE`?

I tried the following code :

```
ss.udf.register("REPLACE", REGEXP_REPLACE)           // This doesn't work
ss.udf.register("sum_in_all", sumInAll)
ss.udf.register("mod", mod)
ss.udf.register("average_in_all", averageInAll)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import it with an alias :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{regexp_replace => replace }
df.show
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  5|
|  6|
|  7|
|  8|
|  9|
+---+

df.withColumn("replaced", replace($"id", "(\\d)" , "$1+1") ).show

+---+--------+
| id|replaced|
+---+--------+
|  0|     0+1|
|  1|     1+1|
|  2|     2+1|
|  3|     3+1|
|  4|     4+1|
|  5|     5+1|
|  6|     6+1|
|  7|     7+1|
|  8|     8+1|
|  9|     9+1|
+---+--------+
```

To do it with Spark SQL, you'll have to re-register the function in Hive with a different name :

```
sqlContext.sql(" create temporary function replace 
                 as 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpReplace' ")

sqlContext.sql(""" select replace("a,b,c", "," ,".") """).show
+-----+
|  _c0|
+-----+
|a.b.c|
+-----+
```

Comment: thanks a lot. how can I use in spark-sql ?  like `spark.sql("select REPLACE('hello world', 'or', 'ro')")`

Comment: @曾海云 I don't think that is possible with Spark SQL.

Comment: ok, I intended to use udf to register regexp_replace as replace, but failed.

Comment: @zzzhy I think that there is a set of keywords on which you can't touch

Comment: @philantrovert not indeed for our users use common sql-like query to get filtered data which prefers to using names which 'duplicated from' database.

Comment: @eliasah I think it's not the 'keyword' problem. the following test-case can get through. `val replace: (String, String, String) => String = (origin, source, target) => {
      StringUtils.replace(origin, source, target)
    }
    spark.udf.register("replace", replace)   ;assert(spark.sql("select REPLACE('hello world', 'or', 'ro')").collect()
      === spark.sql("select REGEXP_REPLACE('hello world', 'or', 'ro')").collect())`