# How to Override native Spark/Hive UDFs using SparkSession in Spark2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

How do I override native spark/hive UDFs using SparkSession in Spark2. This is required to alter default behavior that spark/hive provides which in turn will allow us to support legacy code base. example use of '**trunc**'.

**Observation: I am able to override native function both in hive and spark, but unable to achieve method overloading in Spark 2 using SparkSession.**

Table Desc

```
hive> desc sample_table;
id                      int
name                    string
time_stamp              timestamp
```

View records:

```
hive> select * from sample_table;
1       Pratap Chandra Dhan     NULL
2       Dyuti Ranjan Nayak      2016-01-01 00:00:00
3       Rajesh  NULL
```

Custom Hive UDF

```
package com.spark2.udf;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;

public class Trunc extends UDF {

public Integer evaluate(Timestamp input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return input.getDay();
    }
}

public Long evaluate(Long input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return input * 1000;
    }
}

public String evaluate(Timestamp input, String str) {
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return input.getMonth() + "_" + str;
    }
}
}
```

Try running '**trunc**' function using one arg, it will fail as it takes two args

```
hive> select trunc(time_stamp)  from sample_table;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10015]: Line 1:7 Arguments length mismatch 'time_stamp': trunc() requires 2 argument, got 1
```

Now lets override using our above class, for that We need to add jar and register trunc function.

```
hive> list jars;

/*add jars*/
hive> add jar spar2-udf-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;
Added [spar2-udf-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar] to class path
Added resources: [spar2-udf-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar]

/*register trunc function*/
hive> CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION trunc AS "com.spark2.udf.Trunc";
OK
Time taken: 0.25 seconds

/*test trunc function that takes timestamp*/
hive> select trunc(time_stamp)  from sample_table;
OK
NULL
5
NULL
Time taken: 0.287 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)

/*test all function behaviour*/
hive> select trunc(id),trunc(time_stamp),trunc(time_stamp,name)  from 
sample_table;
OK
1000    NULL    NULL
2000    5       0_Dyuti Ranjan Nayak
3000    NULL    NULL
Time taken: 0.054 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

**Approach I: using SparkSession in spark2 [does not work]:**

```
 scala> spark.sql("list jars").show;
 +-------+
 |Results|
 +-------+
 +-------+

 scala> spark.sql("add jar spar2-udf-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar").show;
 +------+
 |result|
 +------+
 |     0|
 +------+

 scala> spark.sql("list jars").collect.foreach(println)
 [spark://10.113.57.185:47278/jars/spar2-udf-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar]


scala> spark.sql("CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION trunc AS 'com.spark2.udf.Trunc'").collect.foreach(println)
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Function trunc already exists;     
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.registerFunction(SessionCatalog.scala:1083)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateFunctionCommand.run(functions.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:182)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:636)
... 48 elided
```

**Approach II: Using HiveContext in Spark2 [does not work]:**

This approach was working till Spark 1.6, but since HiveContext is depreccated in Spark 2.x. this also does not work.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

scala> val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
hiveContext: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext@e4b9a64

scala> hiveContext.sql("CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION trunc AS 'com.spark2.udf.Trunc'").collect.foreach(println)
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Function trunc already exists;
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.registerFunction(SessionCatalog.scala:1083)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateFunctionCommand.run(functions.scala:63)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:182)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:67)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:636)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:691)
... 48 elided
```

**Approach III: Using SparkSession in Spark2 [It works]:**

```
scala> spark.udf.register("trunc", (input:java.sql.Timestamp,str:String) => 
input.getMonth() + "_" + str)
...

scala> spark.sql("select trunc(time_stamp,name)  from sample_table where 
id=2").collect.foreach(println);
[0_Dyuti Ranjan Nayak]
```

**but method overloading wont work and following query will fail:**

```
scala>spark.sql("select trunc(id),trunc(time_stamp),trunc(time_stamp,name)  
from sample_table").collect.foreach(println)
```

Comment: You can rename the existing `trunc` function to `trunc1` or `trunc_orig` or something as shown here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47747980/how-to-rename-an-existing-spark-sql-function/47748048#47748048

Comment: @philantrovert, we can not rename, it has to be `trunc`, the reason being, We need to align `trunc` behavior to our legacy product.